# Android Scenes & Transitions, logic doesn't work after first scene

Tags: android, android-transitions

I have an AuthorizationActivity with 3 scenes, which are simply different number of fields, so when user comes on Activity runs first **"splash scene", with 2 buttons(Sign In, Sign Up)**, by clicking on each user sees the same activity but different scenes. By clicking **on Back button I change scene**, for example if user on the Sign In, back click -> change scene to splash.

And now I have a problem, when he at **first time went to Sign In**, typing text(validation works,logic works, **all is cool**), then he decides go back, and **go again to SignIn** (logic is broken, validation doesn't work, **things are bad**)

Memory is growing, so I guess the problem is a multiple objects of scenes, because if I on SignIn and all fields filled correctly debug shows that my model is empty. I appreciate any help)

go SignUp

```
fun goSignUpTransition(v: View) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootContainer_AS, changeBounds)
        back.isClickable = true
        splashSceneFields.sceneRoot.visibility = View.GONE
        val layoutParams = innerArcContainer_SSM.layoutParams
        layoutParams.height = signUpHeaderHeight
        innerArcContainer_SSM.layoutParams = layoutParams

        val pp = localRoot.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
        pp.topMargin = signUpMargin

        this.signUpContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        this.signUpContainer.animate().alpha(1f).start()
        this.wellaLogo_SA.visibility = View.GONE
        this.wellaLogo_SA.animate().alpha(0f).start()
        this.title_SSM.text = getString(R.string.sign_up_text)

        val alpha = this.toolbarControllers_SSM.animate().alpha(1f)
        alpha.duration = ANIM_DURATION
        alpha.start()

        TransitionManager.go(signUpScene)
        splashSceneFields.sceneRoot.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    }
```

go back

```
fun goSplashTransition(v: View) {
    galleryBottomSheet.photoURI = null
    userPhoto_SSM.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_photo_upload_white_big)

    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootContainer_AS, changeBounds)
    splashSceneFields.sceneRoot.visibility = View.GONE

    val layoutParams = innerArcContainer_SSM.layoutParams
    layoutParams.height = preAnimDimension
    innerArcContainer_SSM.layoutParams = layoutParams

    val pp = localRoot.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    pp.topMargin = 0

    val animator = wellaLogo_SA.animate()
    animator.scaleX(1f).scaleY(1f).duration = ANIM_DURATION
    animator.start()

    val alpha = this.toolbarControllers_SSM.animate().alpha(0f)
    alpha.duration = ANIM_DURATION
    alpha.start()

    this.signUpContainer.animate().alpha(0f).start()
    this.signUpContainer.visibility = View.GONE
    this.wellaLogo_SA.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    this.wellaLogo_SA.animate().alpha(1f).start()


    TransitionManager.go(splashSceneFields)
    back.isClickable = false
    splashSceneFields.sceneRoot.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Comment: add some more code where you switch between scenes

Comment: @aju, I am switching generally as shown above, all is simply

Comment: @aju, I've added, it's on Kotlin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found solution by myself, every time when scenes comes, I had to find all my views again, set listeners and so on. Scene has a `setEnterAction` where you'd like to bind UI or update your model(this I supposed to do) and `setExitAction` if you have something you have to release/clear/update, do it there.